Texstudio 4.7.3 crashes as soon I close denotation.tex
Backtrace file contains:
unknown at 7ff615c33de7 (TXS-Version 4.7.3 R )
[bt] 00007ff61591a8b9  q+3508877
[bt] 00007ff615919acb  q+3505311
[bt] 00007ff6158327f7  q+2558411

It doesn't crash when I close any other file, only denotation.tex which I use to add dictionary terms.

Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you asked the support of TeXStudio?

You can find the texstudio issue tracker at https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues?q=is%3Aissue+
